# Zend_Form: Get only modified values

Tags: zend-framework

In zend form is it possible to get only the modified values? I don't want to update all the fields again during an update.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess to fill the form with the values from your `$_POST`. This contains usually all form fields.

So you have to do this on your own: 
You can compare the values manually to the values that you initially set to the form.

You could use `array_diff_assoc($form->getValues(),$valuesfromDatabase)`